# "'\w' is an unrecognized escape" in grep

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I'm using grep in some projects in R (which uses a `perl=TRUE` flag) and for the life of me I can't figure out why R keeps throwing errors. My query is as follows:

```
d$SomeColumn[grep("(?ix)<VNW[^;]*;(dis|dat)> \w*<N\(", d$Right, perl=TRUE)] <- 1
```

However, R throws the following error:

```
Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""<VNW[^;]*;(dis|dat)> \w"
```

Comment: @anubhava No, but why is that necessary? Isn't it escaped yet?

Comment: It is because regex is being entered as string in double quotes. String needs one escaping and regex engine needs another escaping. e.g. `\\w` is passed to regex engine as `\w`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes one more time in r.

```
d$SomeColumn[grep("(?ix)<VNW[^;]*;(dis|dat)> \\w*<N\\(", d$Right, perl=TRUE)] <- 1

                                              |     |
```